# How to change ion-option direction to right in ion-select?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic-view

I am developing an app using ionic 2. 
I want to use rtl direction for ion-option in ion-select. Because i want to show arabic text in ion-option.

Answer (score 1):

Just put this css rules in your `src/app/app.scss` file:

```
.alert-title {
   text-align: center;
}
.alert-radio-label {
   text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: thanks .............it works ...But do you know how to apply above css conditionally....

Comment: In `ion-select` html's code is not in every page section so you must set that globally. search for your second answer.